# Connect players with same phone language settings

Tags: ios

I am working on a turn-based multiplayer game using game center. The game also use Spanish localisation. It is enabled by reading the device language settings. Now my requirement is: When i start a turn based match, my opponent should have the same language setting in his/her phone as I am having. How can I make this possible.

I use the following code to connect

```
- (void)findTurnBasedMatchWithViewcontroller:(UIViewController *)viewController forDelegate:(id)argDelegate {
self.delegate = argDelegate;
presentingViewController = viewController;
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
[manager setCurrentGameType:kTurnBased];
GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;
mmvc.showExistingMatches = NO;
[presentingViewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:^(void) {

 }];
}
```

Comment: I never wrote a single line of code for iOS in my life. Still I was able to answer this question just by looking up the documentation. So I am afraid I have to downvote this question because it "does not show any research effort". When I was able to find an answer without knowing anything at all about the technology involved, you should have been able to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `request.playerGroup` property to different values depending on the users language. An excerpt from [the documentation of GKMatchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> playerGroup
>
> A number identifying a subset of players allowed to join the match.
>
> @property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger playerGroup
>
> If your game sets the playerGroup property, only players whose requests share the same playerGroup value are automatched by Game Center. The value of a player group is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks dude. Will this work on a turn based game? Mine is a turn based one.

Comment: @AbinGeorge I see no reason why it should not work for a turn-based game.